# ReflectionTestUtils set field with spring value annotation returning NPE

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I have a class which implements a interface. That class has a private double field `field1` which reads value from application properties using `@Value` spring annotation.

I'm developing tests and I need to populate that field from that class. To achieve that I'm using:

```
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(Class.class, "field1", value, double.class);
```

I'm getting always null pointer exception, but the debug log shows:

`DEBUG org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils - Setting field 'field1' of type [double] on target object [null] or target class [class com.a.b.c.Class] to value [value]`.

Does someone know how can I set value to this field using reflection or just how to populate some value to this class field? I don't have any instance of that class, but interfaces.

Answer (score 10):

the first argument is the instance, not the class

```
YourClass object = new YourClass();
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(object, "field1", value);
```

Comment: This is the key 
`the first argument is the instance, not the class`

Comment: @yas absolutely. The order of the commands is important. To be clear, changing the field makes no sense, if the object containing it is yet not 'alive'.

Answer (score 4):

It should be an instance of an object that you pass to setField.
For instanse assuming Mockito it should go:

```
@InjectMocks
AbcdImpl abcdImpl;
```

and then:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(abcdImpl, "field", "value");
```

Comment: Yes, `@InjectMocks` is required if you're going to be calling `setField`. `@Autowired` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

here is my some example test for ReflectionTestUtils.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class RedisConfigTest {


    @Mock
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory;

    @Mock
    RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private RedisConfig config = new RedisConfig(jedisConnectionFactory, redisTemplate);



    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(config, "master", "mymaster");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(config, "redisSentinels", "localhost:6379");
        lenient().when(config.jedisConnectionFactory()).thenReturn(jedisConnectionFactory);
        lenient().when(config.redisTemplate()).thenReturn(redisTemplate);

    }

    @Test
    void jedisConnectionFactory(){
        Assertions.assertEquals(config.jedisConnectionFactory(), jedisConnectionFactory);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not say why you get the NullPointer but I use the following form as class level annotation in my tests to set a property:

```
...
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "key.from.properties=myValue",
})
public class MyTest {
```

Comment: But I have one class `MyTest` which in the process uses `AnotherClass` which has a private field injected. Can I still use your way?

Comment: Sure, my fields are mostly private as well. It's not about spring setting plain the private field but just delivering the right value to the field via the @Value annotation. Of course your test class has to be annotated with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`